# Consolidated QTP Result for Multiple Tests inside email

Tags: automated-tests, qtp, hp-quality-center

I am running multiple QTP Scripts from Quality Center. On running the scripts, email is sent indicating PASS/FAIL result for each test set. If script fails to see the detail report we have to go in QC/QTP Report.Is there any way to get detail report in mail?
Also is there any way to get consolidated report with detail for whole test sets?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Yes, This is possible to do. If you are using Microsoft Outlook , Lotus notes... than you need to prepare an object of the application and can access the QC using OTA. Download the results into an excel sheet and send the excel as an attachment to any users. Even you can do the same using QC mailing server, But again using OTA of QC.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But the problem is how to get the result of all executed script in excel sheet. Because for each script executed, result get saved in folder of that scrip only. There is no consolidated report we get in QTP.